# croco block dynamic display based on checkbox filter field is not working

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have checkboxes for several property types which are custom post types. I want to make visible range fields like bathrooms once houses checkbox checked.
I added the settings as follows. but it's not working. is there a way other than this. ?

[image]

SETTINGS :
conditions : value is checked.

field : jet smart filter. (URL with filtered value)

This filter for: jet engine

Filter: property type check box (filter name)

Value: %post_type%

Query ID: house (custom post type slug)